# Failed to issue method call: Unit ... failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd definition file installed, but systemd fails to use it. What might the trouble be, or how can I debug it?

```
ettin:~# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/efl_test_daemon.service 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 145 Aug 18 13:11 /etc/systemd/system/efl_test_daemon.service
ettin:~# /bin/systemctl start efl_test_daemon.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit efl_test_daemon.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: You created a new service file. Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Comment: If you have done reload as mentioned above please provide output of systemctl list-units | grep test

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks, I have been looking for this solution for 3 hours!

Answer (score 10):

Just like Michael Hampton said in the question comment, you created a new service file and you need to run this:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

I'm posting the answer for easy access. If Michael posts his answer I will be happy to remove mine.

Comment: He just ignored us, so feel free to have some votes. I don't think we'll hear from him again.